# Replacing elements in an array in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to look in an array of elements. If an element exceeds a certain value `x`, replace it with another value `y`. It could be a bunch of elements that need to be replaced. Is there a function (code) to do this at once. I don't want to use for loop.
Does the any() function help here?
Thanks

Comment: By "array", do you mean `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't know how one could possibly achieve such a thing without the `if` statement.

Don't know about `any()` but I gave it a try with `map` since you don't want a `for` loop. But, do note that the complexity order (Big O) is still `n`.

```
>>> array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, -2, -3, 8, 3, 0]
>>> array = map(lambda x: x if x < 3 else 2, array)
>>> array
[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, -2, -3, 2, 2, 0]
```

Basically, `x if x < 3 else 2` works like `If an element exceeds a certain value x, replaces it with another value y`.

Comment: I think list comprehension is better than map lambda.

Comment: @Dani the OP did not want a use of `for`, hence no list comprehension.